# Windows 8.1 crashes on almost every program

Tags: crash, windows-8.1, .net-framework

Long story short, I am experiencing often programs crashes on my Windows 8.1 installation. It is orignal Windows taken from MDSN AA site for free (only for students). I have only installed neccessary developer tools like Eclipse or Git and Firefox and a few games. I have all updates and Microsoft firewalls on.

Crashes happens usually on startup of several programs:
Orwell Dev C++
Installation of Microsoft Net Framework 4.5
Camtasia Studio
and others.
I can't see any relation between these programs.
Firefox, Eclipse, Git, Unity3d and all Games works fine.
I noticed that program crashses in most cases during selection from combobox.

Some screens:

[image: http://up.programosy.pl/foto/1_991.png]
[image: http://up.programosy.pl/foto/2_382.png]

I've tried to change compability mode of these programs but it doesn't help. Also it would be ridicoulus since Microsoft Net Framework should works on latest Windows.

About 75% new programs, that I try to install crashes at some point (usually at startup or when choosing value from combobox).

I use portuguese language since I try to learn it by use, but I am the Pole. Any help would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Would it be possible to get those screen shots in English?

Comment: Why are you trying to installed 4.5.1 when it's installed already and a Windows Feature?

Comment: Look in the Application event log (run eventvwr.msc) and look for one of the crashes and maybe post the details from that in your question.

Comment: That's because Windows 8 sucks ballsacks. Just go ahead and reinstall Windows 7 again. Problems solved!! :D